# How to access external storage from WebView's HTML page?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I'm writing an application with a WebView frontend. I'd like to allow users to take pictures and then display them embedded into HTML.

So far I managed to implement taking pictures and storing them in the external storage, but I cant figure out how to access them from HTML, e.g. via the `<img/>` tag.

Steps I did already:

1. Created an externally stored file:

   ```
   private fun createImageFile(): File {
       val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
       val file = File(storageDir, "pic.jpg")
       file.createNewFile()
       return file
   }
   ```
2. Added necessary permission declarations in manifest:

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```
3. Since those are dangerous permissions, I made sure they're granted at runtime (omitting code because I've double checked it works).
4. Exposed the file uri via `@JavascriptInterface` to my HTML page:

   ```
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getSelfiePath() : String {
         return file.toURI().toString()
    }
   ```
5. I referenced the uri from my `<img/>` tag:

   ```
    function populatePicture() {
        let picDiv = document.getElementById("pic")
        picDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' + controller.getPicturePath() + '" />'
        // getPicturePath() returns path in the format of: 
        // /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package}/files/Pictures/pic.jpg
    }
   ```

I realize all of this is not what you'd call a minimal working example but I found it really hard to provide one, since the problems spans over many "domains".

I've tried many different approaches with the URI, such as prepending it with `file:///`, for instance, but none of it worked. What's confusing me even more, is that I cant easily access compile-time resources this way, but for one placed in external storage, it simply does not work.

What is the correct approach? I feel like I'm missing something when it comes to:

1. Accessing external storage from HTML.

or

2. Correct use of methods to generate the URI string.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am stuck here!

Comment: Unfortunatelly I didnt and had to give this up